# How do I create a redirect from mobile to desktop site?

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-302, moovweb, tritium

When a user lands on `m.example-site.com/hello` I would like to redirect them to `hello.com/example`.

How can I best accomplish this when using Moovweb? (Ideally it'd provide the fastest user experience.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using Javascript as well.

When the user lands on `m.example-site.com/hello`, add a `<script>` tag in the head of the document specifying a new `window.location`.

So, it'd look like:

```
<script>
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("hello.com/example");
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the `stdlib` mixer, you can accomplish this by using the `redirect_temporary` or `redirect_permanent` functions in tritium.

The `redirect_temporary(Text %url)` function will cause a `302` HTTP redirect response to be returned to the client.

The `redirect_permanent(Text %url)` function will cause a `301` HTTP redirect response to be returned to the client.

To accomplish your specific example, you could match on the `$path` variable and then call whichever redirect function you'd prefer.  Here's an example for a permanent redirect:

```
match($path, "/hello") {
  redirect_permanent("http://hello.com/example")
}
```